# Question on the foundations of probability

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I am reading a paper of Kolmogorov (*Complete metric Boolean algebras*) on the foundations of probability. At some point, he criticised his own formulation of probability theory in terms of "probability spaces" by declaring (p. 61):

> (...) we are forced to give up the principle, formulated in numerous classical works in probability theory, according to which an event of probability zero is absolutely impossible. More precisely, one must allow that an event of positive probability can be decomposed into a (possible continuous) infinity of variants of which each has probability zero.

I do not fully understand the second sentence. The usual way to construct a probability algebra is to identify equivalence classes of measurable sets, any two sets being in the same equivalence class if and only if **their symmetric difference is of measure zero**. Yet Kolmogorov seems to say that it is the variant itself which has probability zero. I am suddenly confused...

Comment: The "variants" are disjoint measure-zero subsets of an event.